# simple button in a simple android application

Tags: button

I am trying to work out google android tutoria and it's not a simple task.
After giving up on the emulator i decided to test it on my smartphone (galaxy 2, android 4.04)
I also tested this on a newer smartphone (with android 4.2), so i don't think that's the issue.

The code is very simple:
strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">myfirst</string>
<string name="button_send">Send</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

</resources>
```

mainactitivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     />
<button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" 
    />
```

if i take out the "button" section the app works. if i leave it, i get a white screen followed by "myfirst stopped"..

Thanks for the help - i am sure it's just some green stuff i need to get over :-)
Alon

Answer (score 0):

1.- Check your button code.

2.- The button opens a new layout? if yes .. do you added the new class to manifiest?

post your code and your error log.